# Felix how to check bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

I have some application, what used Felix OSGi Framework.

How can I check bundle after update?

I.e. I have many bundles and all bundles are loaded. I can update some bundles in bundles dir. How can I check, what bundles files chagned and what bundles - not changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a [`BundleListener`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleListener.html). It will be called whenever bundles change.

Normally this is not necessary though as there are other means to notify your other bundles of the changes. Typically you would offer a service in a bundle and use this service in another bundle. This other bundle can then use a `ServiceTracker` or a blueprint service reference and this way react on the service life-cycle.